# Angular 6 Datatable row headers?

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm new to Angular 6, I'm very used to AngularJS so this is a new area for me. I have an example table built and working using angular 6 datatable and I understand the column headers and data calls but is there a way to implement row headers as well?

So say example I have a table with column headers as years, my row headers will be the months in the year and the data will populate based on the months to their years. I currently have the traditional example for angular-6-datatable installed and running and trying to study it which I retrieved information from here [nmpjs Angular 6 Datatable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-6-datatable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use material table for angular, I think it good for someone new to angular 2+.
https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

In your case:

```html
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="year">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Year </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.year}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="month">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Month</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.month}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="data">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Data</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.data}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Comment: I did more research into mat and actually like this over datatable, thank you